# iOS not always calling didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory, memory-management

I'm looking for help with a very specific memory-management issue where `didReceiveMemoryWarning` doesn't appear to be getting called in cases where it should be.

I have a straightforward app that's a story with pages. I have an outer view/controller that manages the page views/controller. Each page view has a picture on it of decent size (200-300k). It's large because it's a universal app, so they're all 1024x768, then get scaled down for the iPhone. I have implemented `didReceiveMemoryWarning` to release unused controllers (whatever's not showing at the time). The app works fine when `didReceiveMemoryWarning` gets called, but it does not always get called. On the iPod Touch 2G, if I'm going from page to page fast, it will often just kill the program without calling `didReceiveMemoryWarning` (I put a breakpoint there to see). On an iPhone 1G which has the same amount of RAM, `didReceiveMemoryWarning` gets called at reasonable times and I never run out of memory.

The log prints "Received memory warning level 1/2" as expected right before my code does get called, but I don't see it in the logs in the iPod Touch 2G when my app gets killed without a chance to free up memory.

I've used static analysis and the leaks tool and the memory profile looks good. I don't think leaks have anything to do with the problem. Rather, the problem is that my program doesn't get the opportunity to free up resources when memory is tight. I do want to keep unseen pages in memory when there's enough memory - it allows for quick paging and makes the pan gesture for changing pages work responsively.

Has anyone else seen this? If anyone has hints, I'd appreciate it. I'm also curious if anyone knows under what conditions didReceiveMemoryWarning should get called. Is it possible that my program is gobbling up so much memory so fast that iOS doesn't have an opportunity to free up memory?

Comment: Are your view controllers attached to the window in the normal way (stacked in a nav or tab or just a chain of modals)? Or are you creating a view controller and attaching its view to the world directly without parenting the controller?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by parenting the view controller. My code has a custom view controller that creates and manages child view controllers and that all seems to be working correctly. When didReceiveMemoryWarning was called, I would see all controllers and views getting freed appropriately). My problem was that iOS was not calling the usual code paths in low memory and it lay in asking for too much memory too quickly when memory was already low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory warnings appear to come too late when allocating a lot of memory "too" quickly, especially if the app doesn't spend enough idle time in the run loop between allocations.

Try preflighting (attempt to allocate and then release) memory, and return to the run loop, maybe a half second before you really need the memory.

Comment: Preflighting is a great approach, but in the end, I decided to have device-specific versions of all the page graphics. The iPad Touch 2G would give me a warning when there was less than 1.2G left. The iPad versions of the page graphics were big enough that if the user paged 3-4 times when only about 1.2G of free memory remained, then iOS would just terminate my app. Device-specific versions were a quarter of the size and I haven't run into a real-world case where the user can turn the pates fast enough to run out of memory.